# jquery img doesnt display from array

Tags: jquery, html, image

I was wondering why my code isn't working, normally the first image should be displayed on my screen but I don't know what it might be, my css is prefixed, and should normally work with jquery.

```
<script>

(document).ready(function(){
    var photoArray["p/2012/03/73133.jpg","p/2013/03/73096", "p/2013/03/72940", "p/2013/03/72922", "p/2013/03/72913","p/2013/03/72492"]
    var url = "http://weerfoto.buienradar.nl/"

    $("gallery").html("<div id='frame'><img /> </div>" + "<ul class='fotolist> </ul>")
    $("#frame img").attr("src", url + photoArray[0]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but you are missing a ' from the class class='fotolist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixing validation errors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var photoArray = ["p/2012/03/73133.jpg","p/2013/03/73096", "p/2013/03/72940", "p/2013/03/72922", "p/2013/03/72913","p/2013/03/72492"];
    var url = "http://weerfoto.buienradar.nl/";

    $(".gallery").html("<div id='frame'><img /></div>" + "<ul class='fotolist'></ul>");
    $("#frame img").attr("src", url + photoArray[0]);
});
```

But a better approach might be:

```
var photoArray = ['p/2012/03/73133.jpg','p/2013/03/73096','p/2013/03/72940','p/2013/03/72922','p/2013/03/72913','p/2013/03/72492'];

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.gallery').html('<div id="frame"><img src="http://weerfoto.buienradar.nl/'+ photoArray[0] +'" /> </div><ul class="fotolist"> </ul>');
});
```

I assumed `gallery` was a class here.

Comment: yes indeed, it made it more readable and less complex, thank you. i think there is something with my program that i'm using not my syntax. However i still learned one or two things thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Define array like this.

```
var photoArray = new Array("p/2012/03/73133.jpg","p/2013/03/73096", "p/2013/03/72940", "p/2013/03/72922", "p/2013/03/72913","p/2013/03/72492");
```